# Mocking BigQueryIO

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-dataflow

We have some dataflow job which finally writes the result into BigQueryIO.

We want to write unit tests for the dataflow job. We are able to write unit tests for all the PTransforms and DoDn used in the job. But we have to have unit test for the pipeline or for the job itself. But we don't want to write something in BigQuery during unittests.

How can we mock the BigQueryIO?

We are writing the results into BigQuery using the below code.

```
            .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                    .to("my_bigquery_table")
                    .withSchema(getSchema())
                    .withWriteDisposition(
                            BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this by injecting a DataflowAssert transform in place of the BigQueryIO.Write transform, like so:

```
DataflowAssert.that(<inputToBQWrite>).<MatchesExpectations>()
```

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/testing/DataflowAssert

This will allow you to test the other transforms in your pipeline, but you will need to mock out BigQueryIO using this technique.

Comment: I can test all the PTransforms and DoFn that I use in pipeline. Which covers most of the testing with my pipeline. But for testing the pipeline as whole which involves BigQueryIO, I need to mock the BigQueryIO right?